# How to run database sql script in appHarbor SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, database, deployment, appharbor, database-deployment

I have successfully deployed my `asp.net` web form application on appHarbor and also installed `SQL Server`.

But I don't know how to make database as I could not find any query box of shell where I can run my schema script.

Answer (score 3):

A good way to do is to download the SQL Server express 2014 that will allow the connection with add-on that you install in https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299.
with the SQL management you can grab the Host Name as server name, then use sql authentication and put your `username` and `password`.
then you can manage all your database in your site, and in Visual Studio the only thing that you need to do is provide the connection string that `appHarbor` gave you and copy and paste to the `web.release.config`.